# How to get hidden windows handle of the windows that show hidden system tray icons

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, spy++

I am trying to write application in C# that catch the handle of the hidden windows that appear when pressing the button ("Show hidden icons").

When we don't show all the notification area we have hidden system tray icons.

When we press on the button ("Show hidden icons") that show them we have a new window that all the icons inside it:
[image]
*The hidden windows marked with green circle*

How can I catch the handle of this hidden window ?

When I used Spy++ I couldn't find this window because the windows dissapears when I click any other key on the keyboard.

So I found the handle of the button and used the logging option:
[image]

In the logging results I only saw windows handles of the regular system tray tool bar:
[image]

So how can I catch the handle of the hidden window (the one I marked with green in the begging of my question, first pictuare).

References (links I found but didn't help me):
[How to capture Notification icons properties using Microsoft Spy++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30801829/how-to-capture-notification-icons-properties-using-microsoft-spy?rq=1)
 [Get information about hidden tray icons in windows7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947705/get-information-about-hidden-tray-icons-in-windows7?rq=1)

Comment: What do you want to do once you have the window handle?

Comment: @andlabs I want to find the associated processes to these icons. I know how to do it on the visibels icons: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33652756/how-to-get-the-processes-that-have-systray-icon

Comment: @E235: And why do you believe that the (unrelated) window created by the shell would be of any help? It is merely the host window for the icons. It's the icons in the notification area, that know, which window to notify.

Comment: @IInspectable because I succeed to do it on the visibles icons http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33781788/how-to-get-hidden-windows-handle-of-the-windows-that-show-hidden-system-tray-ico?noredirect=1#comment55331790_33781788 when I had the handle of the windows the icons appeared on. So I believe that once I will find the handle of the hidden window I will be able to find them in the same way

Comment: So much hackery, it hurts. Access to the visible notification area icons is offered through an [official interface](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7383129/1889329). The hidden icons - as the name implies - are hidden. You won't get access to those.

Comment: @IInspectable They are hidden but it doesn't mean they are not there.
If the button that show them can, we also can.
Understanding to what windows this button points can help also.

Comment: @E235: For all we know the chevron button could create the window on demand, and destroy it when dismissed. Your chain of reasoning is not convincing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I succeed !

I succeed to catch it with Spy++:

[image]

[image]

**Code solution:**

```
static IntPtr GetHiddenSystemTrayHandle()
{
    IntPtr hWndTray = User32.FindWindow("NotifyIconOverflowWindow", null);
    if (hWndTray != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
            if (hWndTray != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                // Windows caption "Overflow Notification Area"
                hWndTray = User32.FindWindowEx(hWndTray, IntPtr.Zero, "ToolbarWindow32", null);
                return hWndTray;
            }
    }

    return IntPtr.Zero;
}
```